# I am having an error in the event viewer multiple times

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server, exception

I am receiving below error in the event viewer multiple times:

> Unknown SQL Exception 10061 occurred. Additional error information
>   from SQL Server is included below.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.)

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by high concumning of resources of SharePoint servers (CPU) or SQL server where the instance is. Create Performance Counters and monitor CPU,RAM, disk queue, etc... And you will see.

Probably during Crawl or Backup actions.